# how to use like clause in mysql for variable of double type using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have table shown below. The clause of like is not working for variable of double type in hibernate and mysql. how like clause will work double or what could be the work around to achieve this. I'm getting no exception just the obj the returned is null.

Table:-

```
CREATE TABLE `loc_location` (
  `location_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A' COMMENT 'A-Approved\nD-Drafted\nP-Pending\nR-Reject\nS-Scheduled',
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `location_id_UNIQUE` (`location_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `latitude_UNIQUE` (`latitude`),
  UNIQUE KEY `longitude_UNIQUE` (`longitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table Values:-

```
    location_id latitude    longitude   creation_date       status
    1       19.175934   72.8622649  2015-08-22 14:09:31     A
    2       19.177283   72.8636139  2015-08-22 14:09:31     A
    3       19.174585   72.8609159  2015-08-22 14:09:31     A
```

Query:- longitude = 72.862 and latitude = 19.175

```
select this_.location_id as location1_16_0_, this_.creation_date as creation2_16_0_, this_.latitude as latitude3_16_0_, this_.longitude as longitud4_16_0_, this_.status as status5_16_0_ from loc_location this_ where this_.longitude like ? and this_.latitude like ?
```

Hibernate method:-

```
public <T extends Serializable> T getEntityWithLikeClause(T x, Map<String, Object> ceriteriaMap, Session session) throws PersistenceException{
    T obj=null;
    Criteria criteria = null;
    try {
        criteria= session.createCriteria(x.getClass());
        if(ceriteriaMap!=null && criteria !=null){
            Set<String> set=ceriteriaMap.keySet();
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String ceriteria = iterator.next();
                Object value = ceriteriaMap.get(ceriteria);
                criteria.add(Restrictions.like(ceriteria, value));
            }
        }
        obj = (T) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new PersistenceException(e);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Where ceriteriaMap as following and longitude1 = 72.862 and latitude1 = 19.175:-

```
        Map<String, Object> ceriteriaMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ceriteriaMap.put("lat", latitude1);
        ceriteriaMap.put("lng", longitude1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Restrictions.ilike` cannot be used for numeric fields.

Default Syntax:

```
Restrictions.ilike(fieldName, SearchTerm, MatchMode.ANYWHERE (Optional) )
                       |          |                 |
                     String     String      MatchMode (optional argument)
```

So you can't be able to pass a numeric value to a String argument. Even if you pass it as `String.valueOf(numbercValue)`, you'll get exception because hibernate will try to convert it to numeric datatype as per your hbm or annotation configuration

I've used the following code to mix `like` with criteria.

```
critria.add(
    Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" column_name LIKE '%"+SearchTerm+"%' "))
                                    |                  |
                   Column Name (Not fieldName)  Search Term prefixed and Suffixed with % as per needs
```

Comment: is there any way to get tables's column name from fieldName to which we have mapped  tables's column using @column annotations, because I don't want to use table's column name to make this method a generic.

Comment: @RajBhatia, thats the most worrying part about this solution. Let me see what I can to do

Comment: Well it was nice idea, and it worked very well, but I have got another way around and close to what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RajBhatia, it would be nice if you can share it

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIKE for non varchar(string) types. It works only for String patterns.
In any numeric cases, you have to use gt/lt logic or change field to varchar and parse this fiels to double via row mapper.

Comment: Thank you Sir for the help :)